# How do I prevent subtitles from showing up on my MediaElement?

Tags: wpf, mediaelement, subtitle

I'm trying to create my own Media Player application using a WPF MediaElement. I know that the MediaElement actually uses Windows Media Player as its source and that's why it also loads the .srt (subtitle) file and shows subtitles below the video.
My application is actually supposed to override default subtitle rendering and show its own version of subtitles, so I need the MediaElement to ignore loading and displaying the .srt file.

How do I do this through WPF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought I answer it for other people.
Loading subtitles may be related to the CODEC that's being used. Modifying the configuration of the CODEC through the configuration app it was provided with must solve the problem.